# algorithm for finding order of index variation in multidimensional array data

Tags: algorithms, arrays

Given a set of tuples, I want to determine if the set covers the whole space of possible values, and in which order the indices vary.

This is best explained with 2-dimensional examples:

In the following examples, suppose that:

- X has 2 possible values, in this order: 1, 2
- Y has 3 possible values, in this order: 1, 2, 3

Here are examples of (X, Y) pairs, and the desired algorithm output:

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
```

=>
valid, with order of index variation: (1, 0) - values at index 1 (Y) vary first, then values at index 0 (X)

```
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

=>
valid, with order of index variation: (0, 1) - values at index 0 (X) vary first, then values at index 1 (Y)

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 1) // out of order
(1, 3)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
```

=>
invalid, because the input is out of order

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 1) // (1, 3) missing
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
```

=>
invalid, because the input is incomplete

```
(2, 3)
(2, 2)
(2, 1)
(1, 3)
(1, 2)
(1, 1)
```

=>
invalid, because the pairs do not follow the specified orders for X and Y values (but would be valid for the orders X = 2, 1 and Y = 3, 2, 1)

The algorithm should work for any N dimensions, not just 2 dimensions as in the above examples.

I was unable to find anything by searching the net.

If you come up with a solution, pseudocode would be just fine.

Comment: `was unable to find anything by searching the net` How did you search, what exactly did you (let) look for? If this was an assignment: Did you expect *the net* to learn something?

Comment: Here is a hint for a possible algorithm: First, if the order of index variations is given can you write code that generates the correct tuples?  Now determining the the order of index variations of the input can be done by counting how often the numbers in each column go up and down.